# Is there a Parse.com Dropdown Option using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, parse-platform

I want to display all Parse data from a Class called "Users" using Javascript, I can do it in a table view without problem, but I want display each child as a dropdown view. I've seen something like this being used but I want to apply it to my own: http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/j8vgqvqg/11/

`Dropdown`

Also if the dropdown option is selected that it loads data from another class. I have all data displayed in using relational queries which isn't what I want.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Setup this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhn25wt3/2/) and also put a demo up on my [website](http://ucdi.co/selectTest.php). Take a look if you still need it - just fill in your Parse keys.

```
var schoolObj = Parse.Object.extend("Schools");
var query = new Parse.Query(schoolObj);
query.find({
success: function(results) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
  var object = results[i];
  (function($) {
      $('#select').append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value",object.get('Name'))
     .text(object.get('Name'))); 

      })(jQuery);

   }
   },
    error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
   }
  });
```